# How to set stdin and stdout to default state?

Tags: c, stdout, stdin

I have redirected stdin to file1.txt and stdout to file2.txt by `freopen()`.

```
freopen("file1.txt","r",stdin);

freopen("file2.txt","w",stdout);
```

I have done some operations and now I want to take input from user through `stdin` and print the output through `stdout` only ( not through files ).

How can I do that?

Comment: This question almost certainly has been asked before. Someone should search for a duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

Before you call `freopen`, you need to duplicate `stdout`/`stdin`'s file descriptors using `dup`, and restore them when you're done by using `dup2`.

---

For instance, for `stdout`:

```
#include <unistd.h>

...

int fd = dup(STDOUT_FILENO);
freopen("file1.txt", "w", stdout);

printf("Writing to file1\n");
fflush(stdout);

close(STDOUT_FILENO);
dup2(fd, STDOUT_FILENO);
printf("Writing to console\n");
```

Comment: The generic version to duplicate any open filehandle is `int fd = dup(fileno(fh))`.

Comment: I know Microsoft compilers implement POSIX functions, but portable is `STDOUT_FILENO`? Maybe `fileno(stdout)` to avoid a magic constant?

Comment: `STDOUT_FILENO` is a POSIX-defined constant, which is portable enough (MSVC included indeed). I think that on non-POSIX systems (e.g. embedded systems) code like `fileno(stdout)` won't work (portably) anyways.

Comment: Note that `dup(), open(), close(), dup2(), ` are not part of the standard C library.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica What would be the Standard C way of doing this?

Comment: For portability read the, process it, then write the results. Or detect which environment you are operating in and use the best method for the job.

Comment: That doesn't answer OP's question of how to redirect `stdout` back to console after calling `freopen(..., stdout)`

Comment: It does, because you avoid the use of freopen and dup. And hence the need to reset standard output. I mis-spelled in the comment above, "read the, process" should have been "read the file, process". I applogize.

Comment: That's just answering a different question though :) The question OP asked is how to restore `stdout` to its original state after `freopen`.

Comment: Hope I am not violating the rules by suggesting an alternative solution in the comments? If so I apologize agian.

Comment: No no, alternative solutions are very welcome - but the question I asked is if it's possible to answer OP's original question using only standard C functions (I'm guessing the answer is no)